# confluent-kafka-dotnet - Commit async

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I use confluent-kafka-dotnet in my app and want to control commit of each message, in my case handle message do some job(async) and commit the message, I go over example in confluent-kafka-dotnet project in GitHub and notice that in documentation it's notice that

> commit message sync This is very slow compared to the rate at which
>   the consumer is capable of consuming messages.

So I search in documentation and notice that in the past that was Async method that commit the message but it's was changed to Sync only (can see the Push [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/commit/7721aab6c24f7f1f43216399050c1ac62a84d1c2#diff-b397aaab0847325df75009411d4b52b5)).

So the question is do I have another better alternative if I want to control commit over each messages?

Answer (score 2):

In the commit you linked to the `confluent-kafka-dotnet` you can notice the following line:

```cs
Task.Run(() => kafkaHandle.CommitSync(null));
```

That was changed to:

```cs
kafkaHandle.Commit(null);
```

And the implementation `kafkaHandle.CommitSync` that was used internally hasn't actually changed. In other words the previous `CommitAsync` wasn't *faster* from current `Commit` method. It was only wrapped in the `Task.Run()` that potentially ran commit in a separate thread.

Running `CommitAsync` in separate thread does not make it faster, it only allows to run it in parallel (does not block the main thread of application). So potentially you could continue consuming messages from Kafka in main thread, and perform commits in a background thread. Since they removed the `CommitAsync`, you can create your own async wrapper for the `Commit` method and simply wrap it in `Task.Run()` and do the thread synchronization according to your application needs.

But you need to think if that will benefit you and will it allow to meet the requirement that you described as:

> want to control commit of each message

By "controlling" do you mean that you need to make sure that commit happened *before* moving on and consuming next message? If that is the case, then parallelism is probably not a solution for your scenario.